# C++ why does `observer_ptr<W>` have a constructor taking `W*`?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, c++17

As far I understood, the proposed `std::observer_ptr` is related to `std::unique_ptr` in the same way as `std::weak_ptr` is related to `std::shared_ptr`.

So why does the `std::observer_ptr<W>` interface, according to the proposal [N4282](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4282.pdf), allow the construction from a `W*` pointer?

This implies an implementation which contains a `W*` as member, maybe similar to the pseudo-implementations given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24158171/2412846), which most simply proposes

```
template<typename T>
using observer_ptr = T*;
```

As a consequence, this seems to outrule validity checks as in the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<W> u = std::make_unique<W>();
std::observer_ptr<W> o(uptr.get());
uptr.reset();

if(o)
{
     //u is already nullptr, but o doesn't know
     o->foo();  //invalid dereferentation
}
```

Instead I would expect to *only* be allowed to do the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<W> u = std::make_unique<W>();
std::observer_ptr<W> o(uptr);
uptr.reset();

if(o)
{
     //execution doesn't get here, o is nullptr
}
```

This is equivalent to what one can do with `std::weak_ptr` by locking it, and is imo the central advantage `observer_ptr` could offer over a non-owning raw pointer.

So, again, why isn't it enforced?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you can check whether such a pointer is valid?

Comment: @molbdnilo: as written, from the `std::weak_ptr` parallel. That would be only natural imo, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17561445/2412846) that seems to make the same assumption.

Comment: That answer's "would hold no responsibility [...] for correctly responding to the deletion of that object" says the opposite.

Comment: @molbdnilo: you're right, I was distracted by the question title ["*shared_ptr<> is to weak_ptr<> as unique_ptr<> is to… what?*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536731/shared-ptr-is-to-weak-ptr-as-unique-ptr-is-to-what). I'm still not getting why there is no "*... what*" in the standard. My intuitive candidate for it was `observer_ptr`.

Comment: What would you have it do? Store a `unique_ptr*`? That's pretty useless.

Comment: @T.C.: I agree, but it's more useful than the current `observer_ptr`. I mentioned one possible use case in the question -- validity checking (maybe that's the only, but in any case it adds to what `observer_ptr` gives).

Comment: Not really. You can't detect when the `unique_ptr` has been destroyed - which is probably the most common case where the underlying pointer becomes invalid. And you treat move-from, `release()`, and `reset()` all in the same way.

Comment: @T.C.: I don't understand your comment. When you have a `unique_ptr* p`, and you `reset()`, `release()` or move the pointed-to `unique_ptr`, `*p` becomes `nullptr`. That's good, as you can check the validity of `*p`. When you have a raw pointer `q` pointing to the member pointer of a `unique_ptr` -- as `observer_ptr` does -- and then call `reset()` etc.  on the `unique_ptr`, `q` becomes invalid. And there is no direct way to check its validity. That's bad. This is why I would think `unique_ptr*` is more useful than a raw pointer.

Comment: Let's say `observer_ptr` stores a `unique_ptr*`. `std::observer_ptr<W> o; { std::unique_ptr<W> u = std::make_unique<W>(); o = uptr; }`. How do you check that the validity of `o` after this? you can't. Meanwhile, you also made `observer_ptr` unusable with stack objects. And this is also a simplification because `unique_ptr` is templated on the deleter, so your `observer_ptr` must either be so templated or erase the type.

Comment: @T.C.: Thanks. I take away that there is no foolproof way of validity checking -- at least without changing `unique_ptr` -- and that's the reason why it isn't in the standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> As far I understood the proposed `std::observer_ptr` is related to `std::unique_ptr` in the same way as `std::weak_ptr` is related to `std::shared_ptr`.

That is a misconception. It has no relation to `unique_ptr`. It expresses that there is no connection to the ownership of the pointee.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So, where then is the `std::weak_ptr` parallel for `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @davidhigh - There isn't any. As `unique_ptr` should either own the pointer or contain a nullptr, there isn't much to check.

Comment: @Bo Persson: ok, thanks, I got it. But it's inconsistent to `weak_ptr`. And also useless: C++ protects against Murphy, not Machiavelli. There's no advantage in a class which hides `delete`. However, there is (at least a small) one in a class which parallels `weak_ptr`, see my question.

Comment: @davidhigh The point isn't to hide `delete`, it's to mark the fact that you have a pointer and you're just going to use it to observe the pointee, not sacrifice it at the holy altar of the free store once it is no longer of use to you.

Comment: @TartanLlama: I understand. But someone has to own the initial instance. `weak_ptr` knows who this someone is. `observer_ptr` doesn't (which might be semantically useful for some people). But there has to be a third concept which expresses "there is a single owner and I know it". It is lacking the smart-pointer conception.